# String concatenation or HtmlGenericControl html controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am trying to genrate complex list of items using `ListView`. For every item i must create something like this

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>foo<li>
    <li>bar<li>
    .... Dynamic count of <li>
  <ul>
  <span>Some dynamic text</span>
  .. bunch of other dynamicly generated html
</div>
```

My question is what is better way to generate the html.By using string concatenation like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<div>");
.......
sb.Append("</div>")
```

Or by using HtmlGenericControl like this:

```
   HtmlGenericControl htmlItem = new HtmlGenericControl( "div" );
   ....

   using( TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter( ) )
        using( HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter( textWriter ) )
        {
            HtmlGenericControl htmlItem = null;

            CreateMenuItem( menuItem, 0, null );

            htmlItem.RenderControl( htmlWriter );

            return textWriter.ToString( );
        }
```

Comment: `string.Format`, or `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` are often useful here, such as when you have a span with dynamic text, you can just have `sb.AppendFormat("<span>{0}</span>", getSpanContent());'  It makes mostly-static XML much more readable in code.  If it's multi-line you can also use `@""` for a multi=line string of HTML with lots of `{}` insertions for data.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this way because **this gives me much more Readability**. Looking at this , i can easily imagine, How my output will look like.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<div>");
sb.Append("<ul>");
sb.Append("<li>Item1</li>");
sb.Append("<li>Item2</li>");
sb.Append("<li>Item3</li>");
sb.Append("</ul>");
sb.Append("</div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

**HtmlTextWriter is good because:**

1. HtmlTextWriter is the cleanest and the mark-up is nicely indented
   when it is rendered.
        There is a performance impact as HtmlTextWriter writes directly to the output stream.
2. HtmlTextWriter supports encoding HTML automatically

**Stringbuilder doesn't write to the output stream until ToString is called on it.**